# Is greater than ($>$) exactly the same as neither less nor equal to ($\nleq$)?

Tags: inequality, notation

When learning $\LaTeX$, I saw some relation operators I haven't seen before, like $\nless$ and $\ngeq$. However, I don't see how those relation operators are different from the ones I already know. I'm talking about this pairs:

- $>$ and $\nleq$
- $<$ and $\ngeq$

Do the two operators in each of the above pairs mean exactly the same? If they are, what's the reason of having this symbols? If not, are they at least the same in $\mathbb{H}$, or else $\mathbb{C}$, or else $\mathbb{R}$? ($\mathbb{H} \subset \mathbb{C}$, right?)

Comment: In a totally ordered set yes, in a partially ordered set no.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)

Comment: $\mathbb H\not\subset\mathbb C$; we have $\mathbb R\subsetneq\mathbb C\subsetneq\mathbb H$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\le$ can be used for an arbitrary ordering relation on an arbitrary set. When the ordering is not strictly total, $>$ is not necessarily $\nleq$.

For example, the ordering $\le$ on $\Bbb N$ given by $a \le b \iff a \mid b$ does not satisfy that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is an ordering relation? I'm also not familiar with the notation $a \le b \iff a \mid b$. What does it mean in words?

Comment: @Kevin an ordering relation is a binary relation which is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive. The notation $a \le b \iff a\mid b$ means that we are defining the relation $\le$ by: "$a \le b$ if and only if $a$ is a divisor of $b$".

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me a concrete example of such a set?

Comment: @Kevin you're welcome. What such set? Please precise the kind of set you are looking for.

Comment: "an arbitrary set ... [where] the ordering is not strictly total" :)

Comment: @Kevin I already gave one in my answer. Check that e.g. $2 \not \le 3$ and at the same time $2 \not > 3$

Comment: Okay thanks. Just to be clear, in this case the symbol $\leq$ has a different meaning as it would normally mean, right? Namely as specified in the answer (b modulus a = 0) instead of less or equal to b. So what would $>$ (and $\ngtr$) mean in this case?

Comment: @Kevin sorry, I forgot to mention that. In the case where $\le$ denotes an arbitrary ordering relation, $a <b$ means $a \le b$ and $a \neq b$, $a \ge b$ means $b \le a$, and $a > b$ means $b < a$.

Comment: Thanks! I never realised that there are other ways to order the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. The meanings of $<$ and $\geq$ seem to be the same as when $\mathbb{N}$ is ordered in the usual way.

Comment: Another example, where the symbols have their usual meaning for that context and which was asked about in the question, is $\mathbb C$, where $a\leq b$ means that $b-a$ is real with $b-a\geq0$ (and $a<b$ means that $b-a$ is real with $b-a>0$. Then, for example, $2\nleq3\mathrm i$ while also $2\ngeq3\mathrm i$.